# How to disable the Command + U function for the OneLogin Extension on Google Chrome?

Tags: onelogin

I recently installed the OneLogin extension on Google Chrome, but I am dealing with an annoying problem. When I highlight text and press Command + U to underline, Google Chrome automatically opens another tab and takes me to some sort of "Unit Test" for the OneLogin extension. How can I change the command (Command + U) so that it simply underlines text?

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this. I setup work on a new laptop and this was really getting on my nerves these past few days!! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Open chrome://extensions/shortcuts

Under the OneLogin options, delete or change the unit test keyboard shortcut

Comment: @acheung thank you so very much for this! If you is ever in India, I owe you a beer :D